# Time Machine extremely slow and writing a lot of log entries

Tags: backup, time-machine, ssd, macos

I am using a MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra 10.12.1 
I have to say my backup using Time Machine is extremely slow. I am using an external SSD as backup device. Doing some simple benchmarks writing to this disk could be much faster than Time Machine is doing it. I followed a lot of hints here in this forum and others but not really with success.

More or less by chance I figured out that Time Machine is generating a lot of log entries.

```
$ sudo log show --style syslog --info | grep 2016-11-26 | grep backup | wc   
402026 4892227 71866594
```

I am not wondering now that it is so slow. It generates for each file a log entry and generating almost 70 MB of data.

And below that's one line of almost 400000 identical lines:

```
2016-11-26 16:32:54.557384+0100  localhost com.apple.prefs.backup.remoteservice[1345]: (com.apple.prefs.backup.remoteservice) Created Activity ID: 0x8000000000013d1e, Description: Loading Preferences From User CFPrefsD For Search List
```

It doesn't sound like a misbehaviour.

But is there a way to switch off this intensive logging ?

I assume TS would be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Information update:

In the meantime I have macOS version 10.12.2
Now there are only some few ( less than 100 ) lines of syslog entries.

But the situation is unchanged. It took 124 minutes to write 495 Mbyte of data to write. Which is about 68 kbyte/second.